# Can not exporting renderer shapes added in callback function in highcharts / highstock

Tags: highcharts

I want to dynamically added several primitive shapes like text and images into highcharts / highstock.

Please see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/B6s7V/34/).

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            spacingBottom: 50
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    }, function(chart) { // on complete
        $("#add").click(function(){
    chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 100, 100, 30, 30)
        .add();   
        });
});
});
```

After click button "Add Image", there is a image will be added to chart. **Unfortunately, those dynamically added elements can not be exported to images.**

Is there any possible solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chart.exportChart() function to achieve that: http://jsfiddle.net/B6s7V/38/

The same solution as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474712/highcharts-renderer-text-as-export-only/16520342#16520342).

```
$("#export").click(function () {
    chart.exportChart(null, {
        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    this.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 100, 100, 30, 30).add();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please help me in passing local image (mentioning as relative path or absolute path) in `this.renderer.image` instead of 'http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', because highcharts export printing as question mark symbol when passing path with local image location.

Comment: You can't do that from browser :) Imagine I send you a link, that loads your local images and send those to me :)

Comment: Pawel Fus, Sorry could you please explain it with bit more information on highcharts to point local image file. Actually I am invoking this api call from web application and tried by mention relative path/ absolute path location for that local file

Comment: I'm sorry, but my answer is the same. You can't display an image on a website pointing local image file. You need a server to serve that image (like `https://highcharts.com/demo/gfx.sun`)

Comment: Okay I got it, Thanks for the information Pawel Fus. Is it possible to do when the Highcharts server is running locally (highcharts-export-server)?

Comment: I don't see the relation between these two (perhaps I need more coffee). I think the best would to ask a question specific to your needs. For me, it seems your question is not related to Highcharts at all

Answer (score 1):

When you export a chart, the chart SVG is regenerated from the original `.Chart` call.  If you want to add things after the chart has drawn, do it in the `charts:events:load` callback.

```
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        spacingBottom: 50,
        events: {
            load: function(){
                this.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 100, 100, 30, 30).add();
            }
        }
    },
```

See updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B6s7V/35/).

Comment: Thanks Mark. But i feel it is not a solution to my question. What I really want is click a button to add a image dynamically. I need add different shapes after the original chart been generated. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/B6s7V/36/). In `charts:events:load` callback, I still can not add image to exporting.