# HighCharts: How to include text event to the left of chart when exporting

Tags: highcharts

How do I include the events text to the left of chart when exporting in HighCharts.
The text disappears on export.

ref: http://jsfiddle.net/no1uknow/4PU9j/

```
events: {
                load: function () {
                    var label = this.renderer.html("36 Aircraft delivered to Air 1<UL><li>13 in 2013</li><li>23 in 2014</li></UL>52 Aircraft remaining on Air 2 certificate")
                    .css({
                        width: '180px'
                    })
                    .attr({
                        'stroke': 'silver',
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        'r': 5,
                        'padding': 10
                    })
                    .add();

                    label.align(Highcharts.extend(label.getBBox(), {
                        align: 'left',

                        x: 0, // offset
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: 40 // offset
                    }), null, 'spacingBox');

                }
            },
            marginLeft: 300
        },
```

Comment: `this.renderer.text`, but it only supports simple HTML like span, anchor and some text styling.

Answer (score 0):

The exporting function in Highcharts renders the original chart as it was passed in first, not after it's been modified by further actions, such as using the renderer to add text. Fortunately, you can manually call the `exportChart` function and pass in additional chart settings, including functions for adding the renderer text. This will let you do what you want.

See here for details: [Can not exporting renderer shapes added in callback function in highcharts / highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508849/can-not-exporting-renderer-shapes-added-in-callback-function-in-highcharts-hig)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [renderer text](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) instead of `html` (which is not exported).

```
 events: {
                load: function () {
                    var label = this.renderer.text("36 Aircraft delivered to Air 1<UL><li>13 in 2013</li><li>23 in 2014</li></UL>52 Aircraft remaining on Air 2 certificate",100,100)
                    .css({
                        width: '180px'
                    })
                    .attr({
                        'stroke': 'silver',
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        'r': 5,
                        'padding': 10
                    })
                    .add();

                    label.align(Highcharts.extend(label.getBBox(), {
                        align: 'left',

                        x: 0, // offset
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: 40 // offset
                    }), null, 'spacingBox');

                }
            },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4PU9j/1/