# Highcharts don't export custom SVG elements added after created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

Im working with Highcharts 6.0.7 in React, specifically Im adding SVG elements to the chart, using the chart.renderer object, after the chart was created, not in the constructor callback. The problem is when I try to export the chart, either the online and the offline module don't export the custom SVG.

I need a solution for this problem cause my client want to draw annotations and lines inside the chart.

I attach a jsfiddle [example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/Reinier/73dyyvLg/2/).

```
// create the chart
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            redraw: function () {
                var label = this.renderer.label('The chart was just redrawn', 100, 120)
                    .attr({
                        fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                        padding: 10,
                        r: 5,
                        zIndex: 8
                    })
                    .css({
                        color: '#FFFFFF'
                    })
                    .add();

            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});


// activate the button
$('#button').click(function () {
    chart.addSeries({
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
    });

    $('#button').off('click');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not exporting renderer shapes added in callback function in highcharts / highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508849/can-not-exporting-renderer-shapes-added-in-callback-function-in-highcharts-hig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the options 'left by a user' and recreate shapes/labels on the export chart load event with those kept options. Depending on what a user can do in your chart keeping the options might be complex but for simple shapes/labels it comes down to saving attrs and css options.

```
// the labels storage
const customLabels = []

// a util for creating a label and saving its options
function createLabel (renderer, { args, attr, css }) {
   const label = renderer.label(...args).attr(attr).css(css).add()

   label.userOptions = { args, attr, css}

   return label
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            redraw () {
                const userOptions = {
                  args: ['The chart was just redrawn', 100, 120],
                  attr: {
                        fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                        padding: 10,
                        r: 5,
                        zIndex: 8
                    },
                    css: {
                        color: '#FFFFFF'
                    }
                }

               const label = createLabel(this.renderer, userOptions)

               customLabels.push(label)
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }],

    exporting: {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          events: {
            load () { // recreate the labels
              this.labelsForExport = customLabels.map(({ userOptions }) => createLabel(this.renderer, userOptions))
            },

            destroy () { // clean up the labels
              this.labelsForExport.forEach(label => label.destroy())
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

**[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/c3ma9cpt/)**

Comment: Thanks you very much!