# Highcharts text in the exported image only

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to put some text in the highchart when it is exported. i.e. the text won't be visible in the web page but when you export the chart to png, jpeg, pdf ... it will be there in the bottom of the graph below the x axis.

I tried multiple things:

1. `text.renderer()`, but this puts the text in the graph as well
2. Even doing a `display:none;` on the text didn't work out.

Any hint on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474712/highcharts-renderer-text-as-export-only)

Comment: @ODelibalta any way to get this done when user click on the export icon instead of onload.

Comment: That should fire on `exportChart` event load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In exporting options, you can define chart options which will be available only for the chart in the exported image.

```
exporting: {
  chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function () {
          this.renderer.text('text for the exported image', 100, 100).add()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/6j97LeLx/

Comment: I dont know who gave this a -1 but this is absolutely correct answer. Really appreciate this! :)

Comment: I want to get the container div inside `exporting.chartOptions.chart.events.load` but inside this `this` is a different element with different `container` and `renderTo` values. Any idea why?

Comment: Basically, on exporting it is created a whole new chart within a temporary div element. To access old chart you can save the old chart to the variable and access it from the load exporting callback.